# Getting value from non-input element using htmx

Tags: htmx

The example below, from [htmx's docs](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-include/) includes the value of the `input` field with the request to `/register`

I'd like to find a way to include the content of the `button` tag (i.e. "Register~). I've tried `hx-include="[name='button_name']"` but it seems like `hx-include` only works with input elements.

After going through their docs I can't seem to find a way to send the text of, say, a `<p>` element along with the request.

Any ideas?

```
<div>
    <button hx-post="/register" name='button_name hx-include="[name='email']">
        Register!
    </button>
    Enter email: <input name="email" type="email"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate hidden input fields and include them in the request, e.g.:

```
<div>
    <button hx-post="/register" name='button_name hx-include="[name='email'],[name='op']">
        Register!
    </button>
    Enter email: <input name="email" type="email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="op" value="register" />
</div>
```

Including text-formatting/sectioning HTML elements in the request does not make sense, since you already know that information on the backend when you generate the page itself.